# Implementation of then for std::future results in compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

When I try to compile this implementation Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, the compiler says that I have referenced deleted copy constructor of `std::future`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

template <typename T, typename Func>
auto then(std::future<T> future, Func func) -> std::future<decltype(func(future))>
{
    return std::async([] (std::future<T> future, Func func) {
        future.wait();
        func(std::move(future));
    }, std::move(future), std::move(func));
}


int main()
{
    then(std::async([] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        return 5;
    }), [] (std::future<int> f) {
        std::cout << f.get();
    }).get();
}
```

This is the message from the compiler

```
1>------ Build started: Project: temp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  temp.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(58): error C2280: 'std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>::future(const std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(1140) : see declaration of 'std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>::future'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(118) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Result_of<_Fty,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type> ,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f> &>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(975) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::result_of<_Funx (std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type> ,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f> &)>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Funx=then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>
1>  ,            _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(283) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Do_call_ret<false,_Ret,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::tuple<std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>,std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<0,1>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<false,_Ret,_Ty,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>
1>  ,            _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>  ,            _Rx=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<false,_Ret,_Ty,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>
1>  ,            _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>  ,            _Rx=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(226) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,>::_Do_call(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(495) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(735) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<_Ty>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(735) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<_Ty>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(893) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Packaged_state<_Rx (void)>::_Packaged_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Rx=_Ret
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(893) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Packaged_state<_Rx (void)>::_Packaged_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Rx=_Ret
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(1859) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Task_async_state<_Ret,false>::_Task_async_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=_Ret
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(1859) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Task_async_state<_Ret,false>::_Task_async_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=_Ret
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<false,void,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(1880) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Associated_state<int> *std::_Get_associated_state<_Ret,std::_Bind<false,void,_Ty,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>>(std::_Launch_type,std::_Bind<false,void,_Ty,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>
1>  ,            _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\future(1897) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::future<void> std::_Async<then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>(std::_Launch_type,then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2> &&,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type> &&,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          d:\...\temp.cpp(12) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::future<void> std::async<then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2>,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>(then::<lambda_fce0ad2065944df99f1af1e657f83fe2> &&,std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type> &&,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>          ]
1>          d:\...\temp.cpp(26) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::future<void> then<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type,main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>>(std::future<std::_Result_of<_Fty,>::type>,Func)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=main::<lambda_671f15aca9913797c9b157283a9bc860>
1>  ,            Func=main::<lambda_94e6e075e2832fb9a811ae5846fdb72f>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rely on copying `future<T>` here:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
auto then(std::future<T> future, Func func) 
-> std::future<decltype(func(future))>
```

You want to do:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
auto then(std::future<T> future, Func func) 
-> std::future<decltype(func(std::move(future)))>
```